# Unofficial OpenGL SDK Linking issue - undefined reference

Tags: c++, opengl, sdk, linker, static-libraries

I'm trying to get the Unofficial OpenGL SDK Libraries to work and started using the glutil library for the matrixStack functionality. I compiled the source using Visual studio 2010 and moved the libraries to the minGW folder located at my Code::Blocks folder. I moved the header files to the include folder over there as well.

Everything should be in place now and should be compiled for my OS so the following code should work just fine.

```
    // Get rotation matrix
    //float rotValue = (glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME)) / 10;
    glm::mat3 rotMatrix = RotateAxis(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    // Build final matrix from rotMatrix
    glm::mat4 finalMatrix(rotMatrix);
    finalMatrix[3].x = camX;
    finalMatrix[3].y = camY;
    finalMatrix[3].z = camZ - 1.0f;
    finalMatrix[3].w = 1.0f;

    glutil::MatrixStack stack(finalMatrix);
    glutil::PushStack push(stack);


    // Object 1
    glBindVertexArray(vaoObject);          // Advantage of using vao's is that you only have to do all the vertex attribute enabling and buffer stuff once.
    glUniformMatrix4fv(modelToCameraMatrixUnif, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(stack.Top()));
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, ARRAY_COUNT(indexData), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
    // Object 2
    stack.Translate(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f));       // THIS IS WHERE THINGS GO WRONG
    finalMatrix[3].z = camZ - 2.00f;
    glUniformMatrix4fv(modelToCameraMatrixUnif, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(stack.Top()));
    glDrawElementsBaseVertex(GL_TRIANGLES, ARRAY_COUNT(indexData), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0, 36/2);
```

The call to stack.Translate generates the following error: **undefined reference to 'glutil::MatrixStack::Translate(glm::detail::tvec3 const&)'** which is quite odd since without the translate call the constructors for the MatrixStack and PushStacks work just fine which is odd.

I tried adding -glutil to the linker but didn't solve my problem.

Header includes (related to openGL):

```
// Open GL and GLUT
#include <gl/glew.h>
#include <gl/glut.h>

// Open GL Libraries
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include <glutil/glutil.h>
```

I'm still not sure how to find out the correct names to link the libraries to since the OpenGL SDK didn't show this information on their website so I'm not sure if -glutil is correct. I'm guessing the problem has something to do with the linking stage.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using C++ code compiled by VC++ under MinGW? You know that ABI's of those compilers are different? Even the name mangling scheme is different, so that could explain why it cannot be linked. Chack if unmangled version of function name from mingw linker (should be somewhere in error report) maches the one exported from glutil - using eg. [DLL Export Viewer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html) - or is glutil statically linked? If it doesn't match, you probably need to use the same compiler for both library and your code.

Comment: Ahh I did not know that. I thought compiled libraries would be the same on your OS, didn't knew compiler could make a difference as well. I'll compile the library with code::blocks and see how that goes. Thanks.

Comment: I just compiled a libglutilID.a instead of a .lib file and replaced the .lib file with the static .a file. Haven't changed anything in my project but still received the same error so not sure if the compiler was the issue.

Comment: @Robin92: adding -lglutillD did not solve the problem. I still says it can't find -lglutilld. I tried manually adding my library by going to BuildOptions->Linker Settings->Add Library and browse for my .a file which worked. Is there any way to find out what names to link to if the documentation doesn't include these ? Instead of just guessing the names?

Comment: @JoeyDewd: Maybe you should look more closely at the [documentation, which explains what every library that is generated is named and where to find it (the "Native build" section)](http://glsdk.sourceforge.net/docs/html/pg_use.html). Alternatively, you could just use a Premake4 script and save yourself a lot of trouble.

Comment: If you have a source code for this library and a bit of free time, there is sure way to get it done: simply find source of this method (i mean implementation, not just declaration), check in which file it resides (eg. by some multi-file text search), and see which lib/dll requires this file when compiling. It's crude, but in my experience only this kind of method is fully bulletproof ;)

Comment: @j_kubik: Yea I guess that's the only way to really be sure if you don't know the names of the library, good advice thanks.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: Yeah I've read the documentation and used the name glutil to load it in the linker, but that didn't have any effect. Manually adding the library to the project via Code::Blocks did. I'm still a bit confused as to why that actually helped. I'll probably have to look into building and understanding premake4 scripts in order to get stuff like this to work like it should :).

Comment: It's only been 8 years since the OP posted... I had the same issue today, a handful of unresolved functions. I really couldn't make head or tail of it, but I did find a dirty-hack workaround without needing to build the entire library and link against it...  Simply #include "/path/to/MatrixStack.cpp", in a similar fashion to a unity build.

As I said, it's a hack - and I'm sure people have opinions about it - but one nice aspect is it effectively turns the matrix stack into a single-header library (again, not everyones cup of tea but I'm quite ok with it).